# Display results with most matches first

Tags: php, mysql

I need php to display the results from a database with the most results first.

I have:

```
foreach($keywords as $key=>$keyword) {
      $where .= "`title` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
      if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1)) {
        $where .= " OR ";
      }
    }


$results = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE $where";
```

So if someone was searching

> "How to start a fire"

It would display

1. how to start fire
2. to fire start
3. how to
4. start

In other words, title with most matching keywords first.

Comment: Really you need to do some reading on [full text searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) and relevance score.

Comment: Better add an order to your mysql query.. and leave PHP just to process the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue before where full text searching was not an option, and while this is a much slower approach, it seemed to work well for my needs.  Basically, `UNION` each of your results like this and use `COUNT` to count the number of results:

```
SELECT Title, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE Title LIKE '%How%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE Title LIKE '%to%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE Title LIKE '%start%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM Topics WHERE Title LIKE '%fire%'
  ) t
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e29ee/1).

And here are the results:

> ```
> TITLE              CNT
> How to start fire  4
> to fire start      3
> How to             2
> start              1
> ```

Comment: Although this is not the "practical" way to do this it still works like a charm. It will hold me over until i Learn full text or something. Thanks! this saved me hours of time.

Comment: @user2067005 -- couldn't agree more.  In my case, I could not implement full-text searching on a client's db so this was the workaround I thought of.  Best of luck!